# Remove one column from gridview

Tags: asp.net

How to remove one column from a gridview after binding the gridview in the Page_Load event.For example in the below gridview I wish to remove the 'Name' column.

```
Sno  Id    Name
 1   1002  aaa
 2   1004  bbb
```

Comment: Just don't bind those unnecessary columns in aspx pages. Set `AutoGeneratedColumn = false` and use either BoundFields or TemplateFields (Recommended) to bind and display relevant data.

Comment: `GridView.Columns[2].Visible = false`

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code in **[`RowCreated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated(v=vs.110).aspx)** event of the `GridView`.

**Code**

```
e.Row.Cells[2].Visible = false; /*this hides the third column*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In the asp.net grid view you don't have to include the name column from the call. Remove/omit the explicit name column declaration from there. If you can set visible property to no that might help too.